# Variate Font Styling in text editors

Tags: python, text, fonts, size, editor

I want to ask if there are any text editors or IDE softwares that support a variable font sizing and/or styling, not for all the code(where it changes the default font size of the whole program), but for portions of the code? I want something similar to google docs and word, where you can write the title in bigger font size, a paragraph with smaller font size, write some parts with a different font family etc...

For example when I am making notes of my Python code:

"""
What is a Print Statement? (this is where I want a large font size)

A Print statement is a function that displays the content of the code desired in the terminal or on the screen. (this is where I want a normal font size)
"""

print("Hello World") (this is still where I want a normal font size)

Comment: I don't think that any editor will support this out of the box, so it might be helpful if you could post your currently preferred editor. Maybe one can hack something into it with a more targeted search.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with the syntax highlighting as it is? Comments will usually already be highlighted in another color, if you use an IDE (or even vim).